# Easy way to find the controller file with only the URL on Cake PHP

Tags: php, cakephp

Being new to Cake on PHP, I am trying to work out if I have a URL, what would be the easiest way to find the controller code for it?

The URL on my local machine is something like:
**http://foofoofoo.local/protected/admin/org/edit/1**

I have worked out that the location of the view for this file is at this location on my machine:
**/var/www/MyApp/protected/app/views/org/admin_edit.ctp**

I thought what I'd do is do a search throughout the entire codebase for anything referencing admin_edit.ctp. I found two entries, and changed them to see if I had found the point where the view is called, but despite changing the file name on these entries - the app still works when I visit the URL: **http://foofoofoo.local/protected/admin/org/edit/1**

I just want to see where the admin_edit.ctp file is being called within the site.

Comment: It would be something like `orgController.php` in `/app/Controller/`, imo

Comment: Thankyou @Pushpesh, I see an /app/controllers directory but nothing like orgController.php unfortunately.

Comment: Is there anything that may be redirecting requests to `/org/` in your routes file? `app/Config/routes.php` for Cake 2.x and `app/config/routes.php` for Cake 1.3.x.

Comment: I assume you have worked through the [Blog tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html)?

Answer (score 1):

URL: http://foofoofoo.local/protected/admin/org/edit/1

This means I can assume you have a added a route in your `/app/Config/routes.php`. Where this is pointing can not be said since we don't have access to this file.

Why can I assume you have added this to your routes? Because the posted URL is not matching the [CakePHP Conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html) which clearly states that controllers should be defined in plural. Since the URL will be accessing the Controller directly through the Controller, unless a route has been specified, I know that the `OrgController` does not exist. Why?

Try `Inflector::pluralize('Org')`. It will return 'Orgs' to you. And thus meaning the controller should be called `OrgsController` and you should be accessing this Controller via the following URL.

> http://foofoofoo.local/protected/admin/orgs/edit/1

In this `OrgsController` there should be an action (function) called `admin_edit()`, because you have prepended the `org` with Admin, which is a prefix.

It can be possible that the `/protected` part, is part of the URL as well, but do not know where your main `/App` is located and what part of the URL is pointing to the `/app/webroot/index.php` file.

The Views can be found at `/app/View/Orgs/*.ctp`.

If you are still having trouble finding your files. Please start with the [Blog tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html) written by the Cake Community. This tutorial describes all the neat built-in tricks and will get your first app running in no-time. Please read that first!

If you are still having trouble, feel free to update your question and add the `/app/Config/routes.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

Under Cake 1.3, if your application has an AppController (check if the file `app/app_controller.php` exists), you can put this code in the `beforeFilter` method:

```
 debug($this->params);
```

It will print an array on your app pages when you are in debug mode, with the name of the controller and the action used.

```
Array
(
  ...
  [controller] => controller_name
  [action] => action_name
  ...
)
```

If the AppController does not contain any `beforeFilter` method, you can just create it:

```
function beforeFilter()
{
    debug($this->params);
}
```